# Google drive error "Please select a folder on an ntfs drive that is not mounted over a network." Windows XP sp3

Tags: windows, windows-xp, hard-drive, filesystems, google-drive

I have downloaded google drive from the Internet and installed it on my windows XP service pack 3. Everything was fine until it asked me to select a folder for the Google drive folder. No matter what I choose it always says the same error: "Please select a folder on an ntfs drive that is not mounted over a network." I've done some research and I'm wondering if it wants me to reformat the hard drive. Help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this has [been a problem](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/6tke-zB2hfc) for more than 3 years. Google Drive gets installed on a FAT32 partition but the folder needs to be only on an NTFS partition. So dumb that the installer doesn't abort or at the very least complain if no NTFS drives are found in the system.

Comment: That sounds like valid advice. Thanks! I'll give it a try and tell you what happens.

Comment: Sorry for the late follow up (lol). I formatted the hard drive as NTFS instead of FAT32 and reinstalled Windows XP. Google Drive worked after that. NTFS is a better file system than FAT32 anyway ;)